# Probability Flow and Markov Chains

Tags: markov-chains, stationary-processes

There is an exercise that I'm trying to do:

> > $\pi$ is a stationary distribution if and only if $\pi \textbf{1} = \textbf{1} $, and $F(A,A^c)=F(A^c,A)$, where  the “probability flow” from a set $A$ of states to its complement under a distribution  $\pi$ is $$F(A,A^c) = \sum_{i \in A } \sum_{j \in A^c } \pi(i)p_{i,j}$$

My attempt 1:

If we suppose that $\pi$ is stationary then the balanced equations hold, and fixing a set $A \subset S$, we have $$\pi = \sum_{j \in S} \pi(j) p_{j,i} = \sum_{j \in A} \pi(j) p_{j,i} + \sum_{j \in A^c} \pi(j) p_{j,i}  $$

then I tried to multiply $\pi(j)$ by $\sum_{j \in S} p_{j,i}$, then
$$\pi \sum_{j \in S} p_{j,i}= \sum_{j \in S} \pi(j) p_{j,i} = \sum_{j \in A} \pi(j) p_{j,i} (\sum_{j \in S} p_{j,i})+ \sum_{j \in A^c} \pi(j) p_{j,i}(\sum_{j \in S} p_{j,i})  $$

and then I got stuck, How can I simplify this?  I think $\sum_{j \in S} p_{j,i}$ can be removed but I do not how to merge this term in the sum.

My attempt 2:

If I suppose that the probability flow equation hold, then if I fix $A = \{i\}$, then

$$F(A,A^c) = \sum_{i \in A } \sum_{j \in A^c } \pi(i)p_{i,j} = \sum_{i \in A } \sum_{j \in A^c } \pi(j)p_{j,i}= F(A^c,A)$$

$$ \Rightarrow  \sum_{i \in A } \sum_{j \in A^c } \pi(i)p_{i,j} - \sum_{i \in A } \sum_{j \in A^c } \pi(j)p_{j,i} = 0$$

Here, can I group the transition matrices?

Could someone help me to solve this, please. Thanks for your time and hints, everyone.

Comment: Is this a finite-state chain or can there be infinitely many states?

Comment: It is discrete time, countable.

Comment: You need an additional assumption: $\pi$ has nonnegative components.  Notice that if the transition matrix is the $2 \times 2$ identity matrix $P=[1 \: 0; 0 \: 1]$ then $\pi=[-2;1]$ satisfies the stationary equation $\pi = \pi P$ and also $\pi_1+\pi_2=1$, but obviously $[-2;1]$ is not a valid distribution.

Comment: The part 2 should reduce down pretty quickly to the global balance equation.  If you have $A=\{i\}$ then there is no need to sum over states in $A$. And $\sum_{j \in A^c} = \sum_{j : j \neq i}$.

Comment: @Michel, I got stuck with the sums, I update my second attempt for that part

Comment: @Knight : Your update on part 2 still seems to sum $\sum_{i \in A}$, which is weird when $A$ is a single-element set. Likely that is the only reason you are not noticing the equation reduces down to $\pi_i = \sum_{j \in S} \pi_jP_{ji}$.

Comment: @So, in this case the the complement of $A^c = S - \{i}\$, right ?